# Can company-mode complete my code in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I need to edit source code in org-mode.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC cpp
void elimDups(vector<string> &words)
{
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    auto end_unique = unique(words.begin(), words.end());
    words.erase(end_unique, words.end());
}
#+END_SRC
```

In code blocks, there is no code completion.

Is it possible to use code completion in code blocks in org-mode?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do `C-c '` to open a new window with the corresponding major mode.
Then you have code completion.

Comment: Your cursor need too be in the src BLOC. You can try `M-x org-edit-special`

Comment: Also not work. Not only company-mode can not work, Yasnippet can not work too.

Comment: You also need to configure completion in C++ major mode.

Comment: I could use completion when editing a cpp source file

Comment: I think the problem is the completion configuration. For example, this file is not parse by CEDET... The solution works well with `emacs-lisp` or `python` but need more configuration for `c++`

Comment: Works well with elisp too! Thanks anyway!